# Compilation database for BitBake (Yocto) builds

Tags: build, clang, yocto, bitbake

The usual way to generate compilation database for make-based projects is with [bear](https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear) or [intercept-build](https://github.com/rizsotto/scan-build), but these use `LD_LIBRARY_PRELOAD`, which conflicts with BitBake's use of pseudo. And the only other tool I found is [compiledb-generator](https://github.com/nickdiego/compiledb-generator), which works by parsing the make output, but automake has this nasty habit of hiding the commands by default.

Now I suppose most simply configure their development build with the BitBake-generated SDK by hand, but this project has a bunch of separate libraries that all need to be compiled and the dependencies are only defined by BitBake recipes, so it is normally built with the extensible SDK that has BitBake even for development and is very difficult to set up by hand. So it would be better to integrate the compile database generation into BitBake.

Comment: I'd have thought you should just be able to stack the LD preloads and have multiple sets in play?

Comment: @RichardPurdie, you can set multiple preload libraries, but the tools don't support it.

Comment: I think compiledb now can automatically get the compiling commands of make, as it implicitly add `-n` to make, which makes it to show the commands. If you have the output of commands, you can also try this web app: https://texttoolkit.com/compilation-database-generator, I built it to avoid installation dependencies of Bear and compiledb.